# SearchPanel serverside does not display any data

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

good morning, I'm trying to use searchpane with laravel 10 and Yajra and datatables but currently the panels are empty and I don't understand what I have to do to fill them with database records, here is the code I'm using but I still don't understand the part I have to insert in block to see the values from the database, can anyone help me?

I'm looking everywhere but I can't find anything that helps me understand what I have to do to fill the searchPane panel, I changed the method because the data in the tables are many and with this method I can load tables with lots of data in a few seconds but I can't see the panel as I saw it before

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Ticket;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder as HtmlBuilder;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\SearchPane;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\ColumnDefinition;

class TicketsDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build the DataTable class.
     *
     * @param QueryBuilder $query Results from query() method.
     */
    public function dataTable(QueryBuilder $query): EloquentDataTable
    {

        return (new EloquentDataTable($query))->setRowId('id');

    }

    /**
     * Get the query source of dataTable.
     */
    public function query(Ticket $model): QueryBuilder
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use the html builder.
     */
    public function html(): HtmlBuilder
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('tickets-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->addColumnDef([
                        'searchPanes' => ['show' => true],
                        'targets' => ['_all'],
                    ])
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->selectStyleSingle()
                    ->serverSide(true)
                    ->processing(true)
                    ->stateSave(true)
                    ->select(true)
                    ->fixedHeader(true)
                    ->deferRender(true)
                    ->orderCellsTop(true)
                    ->lengthChange(true)
                    ->autoWidth(false)
                    ->responsive(true)
                    ->searchPanes(true)
                    ->editors([
                        Editor::make()
                              ->fields([
                                Fields\Text::make('id'),
                                Fields\Text::make('tipo'),
                                Fields\Text::make('stato'),
                                Fields\Text::make('segnalazione'),
                                Fields\Text::make('priorita'),
                                Fields\Text::make('chiusura'),
                                Fields\Text::make('categoria'),
                              ]),
                    ])
                    ->buttons([
                        Button::make('create')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('edit')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('remove')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('excel'),
                        Button::make('csv'),
                        Button::make('pdf'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    ])
                    ->parameters([
                        'dom' => '<PBfrt<t>lip>',
                        'language' => ['url' => url('vendors/it-IT.json')],
                    ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the dataTable columns definition.
     */
    public function getColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make('id'),
            Column::make('tipo'),
            Column::make('stato'),
            Column::make('segnalazione'),
            Column::make('priorita'),
            Column::make('chiusura'),
            Column::make('categoria'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filename for export.
     */
    protected function filename(): string
    {
        return 'Tickets_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

```
now i entered this
```

```
public function dataTable(QueryBuilder $query): EloquentDataTable
{

    return (new EloquentDataTable($query))->setRowId('id')
    ->searchPane(
        'id',
        [
            [
                'value' => 'id',
                'label' => 'id',
            ],
        ],
        fn() => Ticket::query()->select('id as value', 'id as label')->get(),
        function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, array $values) {
            return $query
                ->whereIn(
                    'id',
                    'tipo',
                    $values);
        }
    );

}
```

```
and i see

[searchPane][1]

but how to write the code to see the real id from the database?


  [1]: https://i.postimg.cc/NfHNKDTg/ecb6d5657d2d48e7cb600868b7d16c82.png
```

Comment: If in the documentation it says like this:Here we define the options for our SearchPane. This should be either a collection or an array with the, but I'm trying everything and I don't get the result, what type of code must be inserted to get the right result? Anyone can help me?